# Can I use the code for the sample in this page in my website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can I use the code for the sample in this page in my website?
Sample page link:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues, not coding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

From the bottom of the page

> Except as otherwise noted, the content of this page is licensed under
>   the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License, and code samples are
>   licensed under the Apache 2.0 License. For details, see our Site
>   Policies.